# Load Wordpress admin CSS into thickbox (or anywhere)?

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin that uses the built-in WordPress ThickBox and I want to load the regular wordpress administration dashboard CSS into this ThickBox.  It does not happen automatically, since I am loading an iFrame within the ThickBox.  Can i wp_enqueue_style() something that will automagically load this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a GET param to the URL when loading the thickbox.  When this GET param is present you can set an admin body class, in which you can hide all the other non-essential admin elements.

Example:

```
if(isset($_GET['tb'])){
  add_action("admin_body_class", "set_iframe_class");
}
```